# How to git grep in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-grep

How do I run git-grep in SourceTree?

I can see the ability to search commit messages, commit SHAs, branches, file changes, and users, under `Workspace` > `Search`, but not content within the workspace itself.

Searching SourceTree Help from the Help menu had no matches for "grep", and [Atlassian Answers for SourceTree](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/topics/753678/sourcetree) doesn't seem to have any way to search for grep questions tagged with sourcetree: [grep [sourcetree]](https://answers.atlassian.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=grep%20%5Bsourcetree%5D) only got one hit.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a custom action in SourceTree... no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked with the latest SourceTree 1.8.3 (and [its release notes](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/WindowsReleaseNotes.html))

This feature doesn't seem to be available for now.
That means the command-line remains the best option for now.

Of course, you could add a "custom action"... if only custom actions in SourceTree accepted input from the user.
2016: Alas, [`SRCTREE-942`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-942) is still opened 3 years later.

[image: custom action]

As noted by the OP [Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm), [SRCTREE-942](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-942) was closed in 2019.
I just tested (Jan. 2023) with Sourcetree 3.4.10 and... it is still not supported: no prompt available.There is no error using `$1`, but searching '`$1`' itself is not useful.

Comment: SRC-TREE-942 was since fixed in 2019. I can't verify this as I no longer use SourceTree.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thank you for the heads-up. I just tested with the latest Sourcetree and... it is still not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I said it was "Fixed" but it merely has a Status of Closed and a resolution of Unresolved.